# k3s: permissions necessary to access metrics server?

Tags: kubernetes, authorization, metrics

I'd like to grant a service account the ability to access the metrics exposed by the `metrics-server` service (`https://metrics-server.kube-system/metrics`). If I create a serviceaccount...

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: metrics-reader
  namespace: prometheus
```

...and then grant it `cluster-admin` privileges...

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: metrics-reader-crb
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: metrics-reader
  namespace: prometheus
```

...it works! I can use the account token to access the metrics server:

```
curl -k --header "Authorization: Bearer $token" https://metrics-server.kube-system/metrics
```

But I don't want to require `cluster-admin` access just to read
metrics. I tried to use the `view` cluster role instead of
`cluster-admin`, but that fails.

Is there an *existing* role that would grant the appropriate access?
If not, what are the specific permissions necessary to grant read-only
access to the metrics-server `/metrics` endpoint?

Comment: I want to do the same thing to access metrics server from a pod with service account but I'm getting tls error ` x509: certificate is valid for localhost, localhost, not metrics-server.kube-system` How did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I've found some info for you, however i'm not sure that 100% helpful. It needs more research and reproduce.

1. check [RBAC Deny when requesting metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/issues/40#issuecomment-402395198). Smth like below?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: metrics-reader
  namespace: prometheus

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: view-metrics
rules:
- apiGroups:
    - metrics.k8s.io
  resources:
    - pods
    - nodes
  verbs:
    - get
    - list
    - watch

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: view-metrics
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: view-metrics
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: metrics-reader
  namespace: prometheus
```

---

2. It seems, there is a [`aggregated-metrics-reader` clusterrole](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/issues/411#issuecomment-707525489) (or there was)

> Aggregated ClusterRoles are documented in:
> https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#aggregated-clusterroles.
> **The purpose of the system:aggregated-metrics-reader ClusterRole, is to
> aggregate the rules, that grant permission to get the pod and node
> metrics, to the view, edit and admin roles.**

however I wasnt able to find any reference to `aggregated-metrics-reader` clusterrole in current version of that doc.

You can find huge example of using this clusterrole  in [Metrics server unable to scrape](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/issues/537)

IN addition check [This adds the aggregated-metrics-reader ClusterRole which was missing](https://github.com/helm/charts/pull/10737) github PR:

> What this PR does / why we need it: This adds the
> aggregated-metrics-reader ClusterRole which was missing, and seems to
> be required for k8s 1.8+ per the metrics-server documentation and
> default deploy manfiests

Unfortunately link in that PR direct to nowhere. I start thinking this obsolete info for 1.8 clusters.. Will update answer in case find anything more relevant